# Python3/Django. Separate project directory from environment directory

Tags: django, python-3.x

Is it possible to have django projects(python3) directory outside of the environment directory? e.g I want to have my projects under /Users/me/Documents/dev/myDjangoProject and environment under /Users/me/Documents/env/myCustomEnvironment and somehow link them together. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936425/django-and-virtualenv-proper-project-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found solution.

1. From my terminal window I moved into my project directory - /Users/me/Documents/dev/myDjangoProject
2. Activated virtualenv from its absolute path - **source** /Users/me/Documents/env/myCustomEnvironment/**bin/activate**
3. And then ran server python manage.py runserver